# Callback and incrementing variable

Tags: javascript, increment

Why does result = array[0] or 1 and not array[1] or 2 when the callback console.logs result?

```
    function test(array, callback) {
        var startingIndex = 0;

        var result = array[startingIndex];

        startingIndex++;

        callback(result);

    }

        test([1, 2, 3], function(result) {
            console.log(result);
    });
```

Comment: You're confusing yourself with the extra complication of the callback. If you do a `console.log(result)` where the `callback(result)` call is now, you would see the same result. Part of the art of debugging is to simplify and simplify some more, and to not be distracted by things that are unrelated to the problem. Also, do you know how to use the JavaScript debugger in your browser? If you step through the code line by line in the debugger, you would immediately see what is going on. Here is an introduction to the [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

Comment: I used the Chrome debugger without the callback and a console.log(result) inside the function and when it gets to startingIndex++, startingIndex is updated to 1 from 0 but it has no effect on result. It stays at 1..still confused on why result isn't updated before the console.log. Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: JavaScript executes your code statement by statement  in the order you write it.  `result` and `startingIndex` are two different variables. Changing one does not affect the other.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are incrementing the `startingIndex` variable *before* assigning the `result` variable.

You have:

```
var result = array[startingIndex];
startingIndex++;
```

Swap these two lines and you will get the intended result:

```
startingIndex++;
var result = array[startingIndex];
```